# Efeito Toggle jQuery de página externa via require ou include PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Estou criando um menu de usuários, ele fica em uma página a parte que é incorporada a outras páginas como index e home por exemplo. Ele assume o papel de um widget que só é mostrado se houver sessão (usuário logado) porém ele é mostrado com efeito toggle do jQuery para mostrar e esconder.

Na página do script o efeito toggle funciona normalmente más nas páginas que ele é exibido via include ou require ele expande e recolhe automaticamente ou seja abre e fecha.
Como posso solucionar isto, já pesquisei na API mas sem sucesso já usei "perventDefault()" também sem sucesso.
Grato por qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Estará a adicionar o mesmo script duas vezes?

Comment: Não intendi? Eu chamo a página com require ou include se houver sessão...então só chamo uma vez

Comment: A minha duvica é se no codigo final haverá 2x o mesmo script. Pergunto para tentar despistar o que pode ser o problema

Comment: Eu faço a verificação com um simples "if(!isset)"...quanto ao código e as chamadas javascript na index só há a cdn do ajax enquanto no código tem tbm será isso? Vou ver...

Comment: Sim @Sergio era isto...duas chamadas, na index e na home (entre outras) tenho que chamar a CDN do ajax e no script tbm...ai tive de deixar o menu em display none e um evento click para o toggle. Funcionou, grato pela ajuda :)

Comment: De nada. Quer apagar a pergunta ou deixo uma resposta?

Comment: Se quiser deixar uma resposta eu agradeço (e favorito) talvez ajude outros tbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua descrição do problema "ele expande e recolhe automaticamente ou seja abre e fecha" dá-me ideia que está a carregar duas vezes o mesmo código.

Da primeira ele dá ordem para abrir e da segunda para fechar. Uma vez que isso acontece sem interação ou seja automáticamente quando a página abre, presumo ser esse o problema.

Dê uma olhada no código renderizado e veja se tem o script presente mais do que uma vez. Caso "sim" corrija isso, para não carregar o mesmo script mais do que uma vez.